# Count the expected value from mimimum

Tags: probability

Random variable $S_{N}=X_{1}+\dots+X_{N}$ has a Poisson distribution(I assume that the author mean than $N$ has a Poisson distribution). wih $\lambda=5$. Random variable $X$ takes two values $P(X=1)=0.4$ and $P(X=4)=0.6$. Count $E(\min(S_{N},3)).$

This is my solluton:

$E(\min(S_{N},3))=E[S_{N}\mathbb{1}_{S_{N}\leq3}]+3P(S_{N}>3)=E[S_{N}]P(S_{N}>3)+3P(S_{N}>3)=P(S_{N}>3)(E[S_{N}]+3)=P(S_{N}>3)(E[N]E[X]+3)$.

What is more:

$E[N]=5$,
$E[X]=2.8$,
$P(S_{N}>3)=?$

Please correct me if I am wrong. How do I count $P(S_{N}>3)=?$

Comment: Do you mean $N$ has a Poisson distribution rather than $S_N$?

Comment: Who is the author the first sentence is referring to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interpretation of the question: $N$ follows Poisson distribution. $X_i$'s are IID.

\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E} (min(S_N,3)) &= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}  \mathbb{E}(\min(S_N,3)|N=n)Pr(N=n)\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} [Pr(S_n=1)+2Pr(S_n=2)+3Pr(S_n \geq 3)]Pr(N=n)
\end{align*}

$Pr(N=n)$ can be computed using Poisson distribution.

$Pr(S_n=0)=\begin{cases} 1, & \text{if $n=0$} \\ 0, & \text{otherwise}\end{cases}$

$Pr(S_n=1)=\begin{cases} 0.4, & \text{if $n=1$} \\ 0, & \text{otherwise}\end{cases}$

$Pr(S_n=2)=\begin{cases} 0.4^2, & \text{if $n=2$} \\ 0, & \text{otherwise}\end{cases}$

I think these are the ingredients needed to solve the problem.

Comment: Could you tell me what is wrong with my sollution?

Comment: hmmm, you seem to assume that $S_N$ and $\mathbb{1}_{S_N \leq 3}$ are independent in your working.

Comment: Could you explain this: $\mathbb{E}(\min(S_N,3)|N=n)$? I guess you used the independency and got rid of the condition of $N=n$ so $\mathbb{E}(\min(S_N,3)|N=n)=\mathbb{E}(\min(S_n,3))$ Am I right?

Comment: Yes. $\mathbb{E}(\min(S_N,3)|N=n)=\mathbb{E}(\min(S_n,3)|N=n)=\mathbb{E}(\min(S_n,3)).$

Comment: I have more questions: 1.$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}  \mathbb{E}(\min(S_N,3)|N=n)Pr(N=n)$ - It is just $\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}(\min(S_N,3)|N=n)]$ Yes? 2.What is the difference between $\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}(\min(S_N,3)|N)]$ and $\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}(\min(S_N,3)|N=n)]$. I think that I miss some properties.

Comment: $\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}(\min(S_N,3)|N)]=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \mathbb{E} (\min(S_N,3)|N=n) Pr(N=n)$

Answer (score 1):

Interpretation of question : $S_N$ follows Poisson distribution.

\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E}(\min(S_N,3))&=Pr(S_N=1)+2Pr(S_N=2)+3Pr(S_n\geq 3) \\
&=Pr(S_N=1)+2Pr(S_N=2)+3(1-Pr(S_N=0)-Pr(S_N=1)-Pr(S_N=2)) \\
&= 3-3Pr(S_N=0)-2Pr(S_N=1)-Pr(S_N=2)
\end{align*}

Each of the probability term can be computed using Poisson distribution.

Comment: Something is wrong because we have $X$ veriable that you didn't use in the solution.

Comment: @Walter The problem is that you "confirmed" that $S_N$ is Poisson while obviously, $N$ is Poisson.

Comment: which is why I asked that question in the comment. If we already know that $S_N$ follows Poisson distribution and you are interested in a quantity that involves $S_N$ only, there isn't a need to use $X$ at all.

Comment: I edited the question. Could you add interpretation of question where $N$ follows Poisson distribution. I would be glad.